# How much was Sawako's guitar worth?

Tags: k-on

In Season 2 Episode 2 English Dub when the Light Music Club gets Sawako's old guitar appraised at the music store the value is $5,000.

I am assuming that originally the price would be in ¥ but because it's the English dub it was changed to $. I had hoped that during the episode I would see a hint as to how much it actually was but the notes Rizu flashes to the club in the cafe all have 1,000 printed on them and the receipt showed only 4 digits where I assume the value of the guitar is.

So I am wondering what the actual value of the guitar?

Comment: Well...[5000 yen ain't a lot of USD...](https://www.google.com/search?q=5000+yen+to+usd&oq=5000+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59.1607j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: it is 500000 ¥  Gojyuman yen. That what shopkeeper says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The item, which appears to be a 60's Gibson SG, sold for 500,000 yen.

[image: Gibson SG]